# Unable to visualise point cloud from rosbag file in RViz

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, rosbag, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a `.bag` file which should contain point cloud and RGBD images. However, I'm unable to visualise them in RViz whilst playing the `.bag` file. This is what I have done:

1. Record using `rosbag record camera/depth_registered/image_raw camera/depth_registered/camera_info camera/rgb/image_raw camera/rgb/camera_info --limit=120 -O astra`
2. Start `roscore`
3. `rosparam set use_sim_time true`
4. `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map dummy_frame 100`
5. `rosbag play --clock astra.bag`
6. Start `rviz`

This is the result I get:

[image: image description]

Here's my [bag file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16zxKuYjUNt3QHBpl2m4MIvTU2-NBzPEd/view?usp=sharing).

Am I missing anything?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331874/unable-to-visualise-point-cloud-from-rosbag-file-in-rviz/) by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tested it with you bag file and it works. You just need to change your static publisher to publish to a tf to between `map` and `camera_depth_optical_frame`:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map camera_depth_optical_frame 100
```

Here is the result: 
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-29**:
I'm now trying your suggestion `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map camera_depth_optical_frame 100` but the point cloud still doesn't show [(screenshot)](https://i.imgur.com/OhOf46N.png) Is your configuration like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IbBM0aAYFbAL8ek2BHp-JGzJiI-zc5pE/view?usp=sharing)?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-29**:
you bag is pretty short (7secs) and maybe it fails to load it the first time. Try adding a looping when replaying the bag and check if it picks up the cloud:

```
rosbag play --clock -l astra.bag
```

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-29**:
That's what I thought too and I've tried the `-l` flag, but still no point cloud. Did you have to make any special setting to get it to show?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-29**:
do you get any warnings/errors when you launch your RViz config?

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-29**:
The only warning I get is `[ WARN] [1567081149.663349526]: Messages of type 1 arrived closer (0.031979627) than the lower bound you provided (0.500000000) (will print only once)`. But I get that when I feed straight from the camera in real-time as well (which works fine).

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-29**:
yes I get the same. There is something wrong with starting RViz with defined config. Try to disable and enable the plugins one by one. Also re-select the same topics and fixed frame when you load your RViz config. This fixed it for me

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-29**:
Strange. Do you mind uploading your config somewhere? I've tried reselecting the topics and fixed frame, but still on point cloud. My `rviz` is a fresh install and I don't have any custom plugin.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-29**:
well I am not using any custom plugins but you can still try with my [config](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cWQ0wA84jCAwjbxav-0XcNvc-YHmA0Jk/view). If it does not work try re-selecting the fixed_frame, uncheck and check the DepthCloud display and re-select the two topics within it

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-29**:
Thanks a lot! Your config works fine on mine, even without `tf` running! In fact, if I have `tf` running and reselect `came_depth_optical_frame`, it stops. Is my `tf` bad? I'm already running it as you suggested earlier.

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-29**:
I think I know what went wrong. The fixed frame should have been `camera_rgb_optical_frame`. Do you know why it's `camera_rgb_optical_frame` and not `camera_depth_optical_frame`?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-29**:
Im glad it helped. You can accept the answer as correct now :) 
Otherwise yes it makes sense, it should work without the static tf as long as the frames are registered in RViz (you have to enter it manualy). The depth cloud probably grabs the frame from the rgb topic (I thought both camera frames are the same).

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-29**:
Can I ask how you figured out it was `camera_rgb_optical_frame`? `rostopic echo camera/depth_registered/camera_info` returns `frame_id: "camera_depth_optical_frame"` though.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-30**:
From [this](https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/ros/depth_sensing/):

```
The Depth Cloud plugin is the first method to visualize the registered point cloud generated by the Depth and Video data streams. This plugin takes a depth image and an RGB image (both published in the same frame_id) and automatically generates a 3D RGB point cloud.
```

Your depth and RGB images are published in the `camera_rgb_optical_frame` frame. I dont know why both of your camera_info topics have different frames (`/camera/depth_registered/camera_info`  has `camera_depth_optical_frame` frame and `/camera/rgb/camera_info` has `camera` frame). However the Depth Cloud plugin uses only the raw image topics which means it uses the `camera_rgb_optical_frame` frame.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-30**:
Its common for the `camera_info` and `image_raw` topics for a specific camera to be in the same `frame_id` since the frame is representing the camera. The `camera_info` just provides some meta data for the captured image while the `image_raw` provides the raw image data but they should still be in the same frame since the frame is representing the camera

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-31**:
Can I ask how you figured that the depth and RGB images are published in the `camera_rgb_optical_frame` frame? Like you said, `/camera/depth_registered/camera_info` gives `camera_depth_optical_frame`.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-31**:
just run `rostopic echo /camera/depth_registered/camera_info` and you will see that the frame_id is `camera_depth_optical_frame`

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-01**:
Yes, I understand that. But I was wondering how you figured "depth and RGB images are published in the `camera_rgb_optical_frame` frame" like you suggested.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-01**:
I didnt at first. I thought all the topics were published in the same frame since they relate to the same camera but then decided to double check by echoing the topics and found out that they differed.

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-02**:
I see. Thanks!